# Java 1.7 - generic error syntax

Tags: java, jvm, java-7

I get from github java project. I have java 1.7 version
there is code like this:

```
    protected Set<Tag> tags = null;
    private final Map<Tag, String> results;    
    protected AbstractAction() {
        this.tags = new HashSet<>();
        this.results = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

I added it to eclipse, but there is error on `new HashSet<>();`

The error in eclipse is :

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Cannot instantiate the type HashSet
>     - Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token
>     - Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashSet to       Set
>     - Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token

How do you think I can resolve it ?
Thank you.

Comment: Is your eclipse compiler set to Java 7 compliance level?

Comment: @RohitJain, I think that should have been an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type inference feature was introduced in Java 7, and your code compiles correctly using the Java 7 JDK. Make sure you have configured the Java version level in the Eclipse project for Java 7 and not some earlier version.